# setInterval() moving extremely fast after being set for nested time function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made a simple jquery load() feature that updates one particular part of the page with a fragment. During each interval of a refresh, it shows a number count down in a string. The issue I am having is the setInterval is either skipping numbers in the count or speeding up after a certain period of time. How can I get the countdown to reset and count down consistently every 30 seconds?

**Update countdown string**

```
<p>Fragment will update in <span id="count_down_text"></span></p>
```

**HTML Fragment/Partial**

```
<div class="divTableBody" id="fragment_records_<%= @post.id %>">
<div class=""divTableRow" id="post_row_<%= @post.id %>">
 <%= render partial: "posts_metrics_header" %>
</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var timeLeft = 30;
var timerText = document.getElementById('count_down_text');

var timerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000);

//refresh partial
setInterval(loadPostMetrics, 30000);

// update countdown function

    function countDown() {
      if(timeLeft == -1) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        setInterval(countDown, 1000)
        timeLeft = 30
        timerText.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds';
        timeLeft --;
     } else {
      timerText.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds'; 
      timeLeft--;
     }
    }

function loadPostMetrics() {
 $('#fragment_records_<%= @post.id %>').load(`${window.location.href} post_row_<%= @post.id %>`);
}
```

Comment: make a counter in countDown function that you increment by one every time coundown is fired. when it hits 30 run loadPostMetrics and reset e/t

Comment: You have a recursive interval timer in the `countdown` function, so every time `countdown` runs another interval starts in addition to the one(s) that are already running. Change `setInterval` to `setTimeout`.

Comment: by removing clearTimeout and changing setInterval to setTimeout. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

By removing clearTimeout, the counter was able to keep resetting without duplication

```
function countDown() {

if(timeLeft === -1) {
 // clearTimeout(timerId);
 setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
 timeLeft = 30
 timerText.innerHTML = timeLeft + ' seconds';
} else  {
 timerText.innerHTML = timeLeft = ' seconds';
   timeLeft--;
  }
}
```